# How to bind button with input field in ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a situation where I'll be adding count of items to generate a bill. For that I'll be looping the purchaseCount input field and the add button along with it based on the number of records. What I want is that the button in a row should be enabled only if the purchaseCount field for that row is filled.

My HTML code

`

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Stock available</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of inventoryList">
  
          <td>{{ item.item }}</td>
          <td> {{ item.count }}</td>
          <td> {{ item.sellingPrice }}</td>
          
          <td> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:5px; width:100px" (click)="onAdd(item)">Add Item</button>
          <input  type="number" formControlName="purchaseCount" class="form-control" style="margin:5px; width:100px" placeholder="Count"></td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

`

Here I want button to be enabled only if purchaseCount is filled in the below line.

I saw some scenarios where ngModel has been recommended but I don't think it can be implemented in my case.

Can someone suggest any possible way to do this

[Sample UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8shpC.png)

Comment: Hi Bharathi. You need a FormArray in your component with enough entries to match up to the inventoryList array. Then in your template you will end up with [formControlName]="i" (or whatever you call the index in *ngFor). There are tutorials to help you with this.

Comment: As @DanHobbs said, or you could also use a NgModel with all the counts, using the ID or some key from the ITEM as the key for the object, to have something like : {'key': null} , and you just check if counts[itemKey] != null